# Control variator with linear slider potentiometer

Tags: motor-controller, potentiometer

I need to replace the rotary potentiometer of a VFD DELTA variator with a slider potentiometer to control the speed of a motor.  I have tried some of those slider potentiometers for stereo and mono use, but they went up in smoke.

I suppose that they are made for 5V and not for the 24V that the variator needs. Is there in the market those slider potentiometers for variator use? How can I make it work with those mono slider potentiometers? [Here is the last one I am using.](https://www.retroamplis.com/Potenciometro-deslizante-Alpha-20mm-recorrido-B10K-mono)

Comment: It depends how it is connected by source and load current and maybe needs a wirewound type

Comment: i will look for that, thanks

Comment: What is a "variator"? Where is the potentiometer used? What was the resistance and power rating of the original potentiometer?

Comment: variator means a speed variator or motor driver. Those VFD delta are well known

Comment: To replace, one must specify, R, Pmax and taper (linear or exp.) These Variable Resistors are called either Rheostats or Potentiometers.

Comment: Linear slider pots are not known to conduct large currents so smoke is inevitable if you do not specify these original part numbers or specs.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "*A variator is a device that can change its parameters, or can change parameters of other devices. Often a variator is a mechanical power transmission device that can change its gear ratio continuously.*" I think you mean *variable frequency drive* (VFD).

Answer (score 0):

I am coming from a different domain, where people often use potentiometers.

1. Find markings on the original potentiometer, for Resistance and Power.
   If no markings, then measure the resistance using a multimeter, the largest value between two terminals out of 3 combinations.
   Power is: P = (V x V) / R = (24 x 24) / R. In consideration of the operating margin (headroom before burning), I would choose at least 1.5 times bigger power. What causes smoke is the "rated power".
2. "www.digikey.com" -> search "potentiometer", -> "Slide Potentiometers":
   "https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/slide-potentiometers/78?s=N4IgTCBcDaIG4EMBOBLBAjANgUwAROwGcVCAXAeyRAF0BfIA"
3. Specify "resistance" and "power", then "Apply All".

I use "Mouser.com" as well.

Comment: according to the manual of any VFD Delta those potentiometers are from 0-5KOhm, 0-10VDC and 0-20mA, meaning a 0.2W

Comment: I probably am wrong to see far difference: 5Kohm 10V is 0.02W. 20mA on 5Kohm is 100W. Is there any marking on the original potentiometer? Otherwise, 5K with 24V (is it?) is 0.1152W. You would be fine with 0.25W or 0.5W potentiometer, providing the numbers, 5K & 24V, are correct.

Comment: Hi user3177225, It just came in my mind; If the connected circuit (I assumed it is on the center pin, wiper) loads, then it has to be considered as well. Unless I see the detail, I wouldn't be able to tell. Do you have link to the datasheet, user guide, or schematics? I only know the principle of VFD but not field applications.

Comment: ok, here is the manual: https://www.deltaacdrives.com/Delta-VFD-V-User-Manual.pdf page 10(or3-2)

Comment: Hi user3177225, In the Wiring Diagram, 5Kohm resistor is on 10V supply. Power on the 5Kohm pot is P = V * V / R = 10 * 10 / 5000 = 0.02W or 1/50W. Maximum loading current through the wiper (AVI) is insignificant, less than 10V/47k < 0.3mA, can be ignored. Point is; almost any of 5K slider on DigiKey exceeds 0.05W, safe to use. If it smoked, probably incorrect wiring caused so. Make sure the center (wiper) terminal gets connected to AVI, and other two terminals to 10V & ACM. If wiper terminal goes to 10V or ACM, it can smoke, around at the edge of the slider.

Comment: that is want exactly happend, The slider will be a part of a more complex control system, needs to be reliable and dependable. Thanks

Comment: Would you please mark as answered? Though I don't know how. :-)

Comment: no idea how to mark it as answered

Comment: How about you vote me up? I just want to see how this work.

Comment: @user3177225 - Hi, Regarding your comment: "*no idea how to mark it as answered*" FYI [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is the main article explaining how to accept an answer. If an answer solves your problem, then you are encouraged to accept it, to effectively close the topic.

Comment: @jay - Hi, Regarding your comment: "*How about you vote me up?*" FYI the OP cannot give you a *visible* upvote, as they have not yet reached the 15 reputation threshold for having the "[upvote privilege](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up)". That doesn't affect their ability to accept an answer.